# Func must be callable when setting up a cron job with APScheduler

Tags: python, cron

My intent is to have a random message from a list tweeted once a week on a random day at a random time between 2am and 6am. I'm using APScheduler:

```
sched.add_cron_job(postTweet(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages))]), day_of_week="0-6/6", hour='2-6/3')
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 379, in add_cron_job
        sched.add_cron_job(postTweet(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages))]), day_of_week="0-6/6", hour='2-6/3')
        options.pop('coalesce', self.coalesce), **options)
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 47, in __init__
        raise TypeError('func must be callable')
    TypeError: func must be callable
        return self.add_job(trigger, func, args, kwargs, **options)
```

I'm not sure what the error means, much less how to fix it. Any enlightenment of what to look into would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The code for postTweet:

```
def postTweet(message):
    log = open('log', 'a')
    log.write("\nMessage being tweeted: %s \n" % message)
    print "Message being tweeted: %s" % message
    twitter.statuses.update(status=message)
    log.close()
```

Comment: A few side notes: First, `random.randint(0, len(messages))` includes `len(messages)` as a possible value, so it can raise an `IndexError`. As the docs for [`randint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) imply, you almost certainly want `random.randrange(len(messages))`. But really, if the only reason you're picking a random number is to use as an index, you just want `random.choice(messages)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `func` isn't a function, just like it says. You are *calling* `PostTweet` and passing the result (probably a string or `None`, but definitely not a function) to `add_cron_job`. That dog won't hunt, monsignor. Stick a `lambda:` in front of it:

```
sched.add_cron_job(lambda: postTweet(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages))]),
                   day_of_week="0-6/6", hour='2-6/3')
```

This creates a function that can be called at a later time, rather than executing it *before* the job is added.

Comment: This makes sense to me and I changed my code accordingly and redeployed. However I'm not getting another error that I don't understand:

Exception in thread APScheduler (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 354, in wait
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 620, in wait
ile "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run

Comment: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 589, in _main_loop

Comment: @Kayra: Each question should be a single question—something that will be useful to future searchers with a similar problem. If kindall has solved your problem, and you now have a new one, accept this answer, then create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but want to help others like me.

You can pass the payload using the args as

```
scheduler.add_job(postTweet, day_of_week="0-6/6", hour='2-6/3' args='Your Payload as dict')
```